# Cannot read property 'cards' of undefined in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, angular8

I am newbie working with typescript and angular 8. Below is my ts file.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var jquery: any;
declare var $: any;

@Component({
   selector: 'app-home',
   templateUrl: './home.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
 })

 export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor() { }
 title = 'project-name';
 point = 0;
 click = 0;
 element: any;
 rndNo: any;


 cards = [];
 cardTypes = ['Get', 'Set', 'Go'];

 card(cardType: any) {
    cardType = cardType;
 }
 CreateDeck() {
     this.cardTypes.forEach(function (type) {
     this.cards.push(new this.card(type));
   });
 }

 getRandomInt(min: number, max: number) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
 }

 shuffleDeck(shuffleCnt: any) {
     for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
         const rndNo = this.getRandomInt(0, 2);
         this.card = this.cards[i];
         this.cards[i] = this.cards[rndNo];
         this.cards[rndNo] = this.card;
     }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.CreateDeck();
     console.log(this.cards);
     this.shuffleDeck(this.getRandomInt(0, 1));
     console.log(this.cards);
     $('.back').each(function(index: string | number) {
        if (this.cards[index].cardType === 'Get') {
            $(this).css('background', 'red');
        } else if (this.cards[index].cardType === 'Set') {
            $(this).css('background', 'yellow');
        } else if (this.cards[index].cardType === 'Go') {
            $(this).css('background', 'green');
        }
     $(this).html(this.cards[index].cardType);
    });
   }
```

In the above code I am getting  a console error :-

```
    ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'cards' of undefined at home.component.ts:28
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HomeComponent.push../src/app/home/home.component.ts.HomeComponent.CreateDeck   (home.component.ts:27)
    at HomeComponent.push../src/app/home/home.component.ts.HomeComponent.ngOnInit (home.component.ts:46)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:21097)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:29495)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:29457)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:30091)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:30051)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (HomeComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
```

On page load when it hits the function CreateDeck, In second line [**this.cards.push(new this.card(type));**], It throws error saying cards of undefined. I am unable to understand how to solve this issue. Thank you in advance. Please do give advice if I am wrong anywhere or in places I can improve.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should replace `cards = [ ]` from your code to `cards : any [ ] = [ ]`
2. Change your **CreateDeck()** function to this:

   ```
   CreateDeck() {
      this.cardTypes.forEach((type)=> {
      this.cards.push(new this.card(type));
      });
   }
   ```

Comment: Cannot read property 'cards' of undefined
    at home.component.ts:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HomeComponent.CreateDeck (home.component.ts:26)
    at HomeComponent.push../src/app/home/home.component.ts.HomeComponent.ngOnInit (home.component.ts:45)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:21097)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:29495)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:29457)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:30091)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:30051)

Comment: @PayalTripathy change your CreateDeck() function as shown above

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (home.component.ts:51)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HomeComponent.push../src/app/home/home.component.ts.HomeComponent.ngOnInit (home.component.ts:50)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:21097)at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:29495)
 at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:29457)
 at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:30091)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:30051)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (HomeComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)

Answer (score 1):

"This" keyword is much more complex then you think

in "Create Deck" function

try to use arrow function

```
 CreateDeck = () => {
 this.cardTypes.forEach(function (type) {
 this.cards.push(new this.card(type));
 });
 }
```

or use .Bind() function to bind the function to specify the current context.

Comment: This did'nt work. Please help me out with this issue

Answer (score 1):

Add code as below in your `component.ts` file

```
CreateDeck() {
     this.cardTypes.forEach((type:any) => {
     this.cards.push(new this.card(type));
   });
 }
```

create the class as below and import same "card" in your above component.ts

```
   export class card{
        public cardType: any;
        constructor(cardType:any){
          this.cardType = cardType;
      }
    }
```